# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called error on trying to call the data from pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, seaborn

I was trying to visualise iris dataset before and after using StandardScaler
Using seaborn
But i got an error on trying to define the DataFrame

I found a lot of similar questions but none of them explained how to convert pipeline data to DataFrame

```
        X = DATA.drop(['class'], axis = 'columns')
        y = DATA['class'].values
        
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.20,random_state =42)

        gbl_pl=[]
        gbl_pl.append(('standard_scaler_gb',
        StandardScaler()))
        print(gbl_pl)           
        gblpq=Pipeline((gbl_pl))
        scaled_df=gblpq.fit(X_train,y_train)
        print(scaled_df.named_steps['standard_scaler_gb'].mean_)
      
        scaled_df =pd.DataFrame(scaled_df,
        columns=['petal_length', 'petal_width',
        'sepal_length','sepal_width'])        
        
        fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(6, 5))
        ax1.set_title('Before Scaling')
        sns.kdeplot(X['petal_length'], ax=ax1)
        sns.kdeplot(X['petal_width'], ax=ax1)
        sns.kdeplot(X['sepal_length'], ax=ax1)
        sns.kdeplot(X['sepal_width'], ax=ax1)
                
        ax2.set_title('After Standard Scaler')
        sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['petal_length'], ax=ax2)
        sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['petal_width'], ax=ax2)
        sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['sepal_length'], ax=ax2)
        sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['sepal_width'], ax=ax2)
        plt.savefig("output73.png")
```

Error

```
    columns=['petal_length', 'petal_width',
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 509, in __init__
     raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
 ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas  My original program is actually really big  so the traceback is really long , but I've updated it with all the traceback related to pandas library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are conflating the transformers (`StandardScaler` and `Pipeline`) with data. The return value of your `gblpq.fit(X_train y_train)` is a pipeline object, not data. To get the scaled data, you can use the pipeline's `transform` method (or the convenience combination `fit_transform`).

```py
    ...
    scaled_df = gblpq.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
    # gblpq is now fitted and contains learned statistics like the means:
    print(gblpq.named_steps['standard_scaler_gb'].mean_)
    # while scaled_df contains the transformed data as a numpy array
    
    scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(
        scaled_df,
        columns = [petal_length', petal_width', 'sepal_length', 'sepal_width']
    )
    ...
```

Comment: can you just show an example of obtaining scaled data from pipeline?

Comment: It works fine right now , thanks for explaining the difference between gbpq which contains the stats and scaled_df which contains the data